# Are there Neon equivalents to Sse2 _mm_unpackhi/lo_epi32/64 and _mm_shuffle_epi8/32?

Tags: c++, arm, sse, simd, neon

I'm also interested in _mm_cvtsi32_si128, but if there isn't one for that it's not such a big deal.

For shuffle, I know that in certain cases I can use the Neon equivalent of alignr (vext), but that by itself isn't going to cover all the situations I need to address.

Answer (score 3):

For `_mm_shuffle_epi8` there is [VTBL](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CJAJIIGG.html).

For `_mm_unpackXX_YYY` the closest is probably [VMOVL](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CJAJIIGG.html) but you will probably need to do a little extra work to get the equivalent functionality, e.g.

```
    int32x4_t v = vld1q_s32(p);                   // load vector from p

    int64x2_t vl = vmovl_s32(vget_low_s32(v));    // unpack v into 2 vectors
    int64x2_t vh = vmovl_s32(vget_high_s32(v));
```

Comment: Note that for common 'shuffle' patterns, you should look at using ``vdup``, ``vget_low``, ``vget_high``, ``vrev``, and ``vcombine`` as ways to reorder elements if you can. You can also use ``vtrn``, ``vzip``, ``vuzp``, and ``vext`` to do some kinds of reorders. ``vtbl`` is powerful, but often overkill.